# Multiple Conditions in Diazo

Tags: plone, diazo

I have a rule set in diazo where I want to say

"if there is no "#portal-column-two" AND also no "#portal-column-one" then do X" It seems to me the rule for that would look something like

```
<rules css:if-not-content="((#portal-column-one) and (#portal-column-two))"> blah </rules>
```

Ive looked at the documentation and cant find anything obvious. I think I can wrap the rule sets like this;

```
<rules css:if-not-content="#portal-column-one">
<rules css:if-not-content="#portal-column-two">
blah
</rules>
</rules>
```

But that seems somewhat inelegant. Id think I should be able to put that into one line right?

Thoughts?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to do::

```
<rules css:if-not-content="#portal-column-one,#portal-column-two"> blah </rules>
```

It's just a css selector. If the selector is empty, the rules are applied.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I keep forgetting that these are css selectors! and they can be constructed that way. Overthinking it.